# Multiple image uploader under editor?

Tags: custom-field, plugin-recommendation, images, uploads

I need a plugin for custom post type. I need something like this:

[image: Mockup with image uploader under edit screen]

Can anyone suggest a plugin which has this feature, especially image upload and "Add another" button option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This metabox class does exactly what you are after and so much more.

[wpalchemy-metaboxes](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a custom post issue - it's custom fields. You can use the [Custom Field Template plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/) to give you this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I created the [Meta Box Script](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html) that let us create custom meta boxes in WordPress. I go in a different way from WPAlchemy (yes, it's worth taking a look) as I think it's easier for developers.